# Handling simultaneous duplicate expensive read-only HTTP requests

Tags: design, rest, concurrency, caching

(updated)

We have a read-only REST endpoint that performs a somewhat “*expensive*“ but transient request. Without client needing to poll, we need a mechanism for the server to avoid unnecessary processing whenever “*similar*” but not yet cached requests come it at the same time. What existing technologies & designs can robustly handle this use case?

**Example**

```http
[GET] /route?start=<latlng>&finish=<latlng>&api_key=<uuid>
```

Let’s say the service above routes users between latitude/longitude locations based on current conditions. We want to optimize server spike overhead because it internally pulls dynamic traffic data from external APIs ($$ per call) & then calculates a custom route (with some tolerable but not ideal time latency).

So, in addition to relying on short time-to-live [server side caching](https://medium.com/codex/server-side-caching-in-web-applications-a9145be1cfa0) to return recently processed requests as well as signaling clients with appropriate [cache-control](https://restfulapi.net/caching/) headers to hopefully reduce their re-requests, it seems we still need some custom caching logic to handle:

- de-duplicating “similar” request query parameters, say by excluding `api_key` & geo-hashing locations.
- Suspend responding to HTTP requests while other similar ones are in progress.

Comment: There is no general solution to this. We will need a lot more information. This all depends on how much control you have over the things that run slow.

Comment: Yea, hoping to get a few best practices, design patterns or pro/con pointers.  Also in this context, “expensive” is not just in terms of slowness since some latency is tolerated, but also considered in terms of backend operating costs (ie: compute, 3rd party fees $$, cost of re-requests, etc)

Comment: I'm afraid this question is too open-ended to be a good fit for the Q&A format of this community. A good question focuses on a single problem with enough information for the community to agree on one answer. Questions about "best practices" invite a discussion, which is not something supported in the StackExchange network. The [help/dont-ask] has more information about the kinds of questions that should be avoided.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Ok, refocused question with contextual example.

Comment: 'whenever “similar” but not yet cached requests come it at the same time.'  I'm a little confused by this.  I think you need to explain what you mean by 'same time' but if the request is not *yet* cached, I'm not sure what you expect to happen.  Are you talking about an e.g.: second request that comes after the first request but before the first request has been completed and cached?

Comment: @JimmyJames: Yes, looking to efficiently handle ALL duplicated burst requests (from same or different users) that came immediately just after its 1st request started but had not yet finished processing (& thus not yet in cache). Scenario: lots of ppl want to route from Venue end to nearest Transit station at the same-ish time (ie: 1-3 sec endpoint latency).

Comment: @eliangius is this a realistic scenario that you noticed consistently in a prod environment? If yes, it could be a good idea to provide details about the pattern you see: do similar requests typically come from the same user? How much time difference is really "at the same time" and how many duplicates are we talking about? If not, isn't it premature optimization?

Comment: Good points. Goal is to reduce internal `$$` operating cost more than speeding up response times. It’s a real issue (albeit on a more complex problem than posted) occurring from combo of impatient users, bad actors & natural burst demand. We typically see non negligible `x%` of requests deemed similar enough within the `y minute` time window results remain non-stale. Parametrizing specifics to defer evaluating cost-benefit of solutions from business use case.

Answer (score 3):

You can move the caching/polling logic into the server, for example by writing some middleware for this. A key insight is that a cache entry cannot just be present or absent, but also pending.

An example algorithm might be:

- determine a cache key for the request
- look up the cache entry

  - if absent: continue
  - if pending: someone else is preparing the response, so wait until ready
  - if ready: respond with the cached content
- atomically update the cache entry from "absent" to "pending"
- calculate the response
- update the cache entry from "pending" to "ready", letting the waiting requests serve their responses
- serve the response

There are lots of variations of this. For example, the waiting requests might poll the shared data, or the waiting requests are parked and later unblocked or notified when the result is ready. The "pending" information might be integrated in your normal server-side caching infrastructure (e.g. Redis), or might use a separate data source. The "pending" state can sometimes be represented by acquiring an exclusive lock on a database entry. A key distinction is whether the progress information is kept in-process or externally.

Aside from caching entire responses, you might also consider which internal calculations can be reasonably cached. This might speed up your calculations, to the point that caching entire responses might become less appropriate. The internal caches might have a "pending" status as well, so that they can avoid concurrent computations of the same value.

If you expect lots of approximately-concurrent requests for the same resource, you could consider *waiting* for a short duration in order for more shareable requests to build up. This trades latency for throughput. Such a waiting duration is quite similar to a TTL on a cache entry, but with the crucial difference that you don't have to actually store the response data in the cache – the response is just copied to all currently waiting requests.

Comment: Two followups:
(1) would this middleware have to be an in-house solution with custom db / redis setup? or are there out-of-the-box frameworks we could just create user-defined-functions for?
(2) Could you explain the “waiting” latency/throughput tradeoff? does this involve accumulating requests in time window & then batch processing the deduped ones?

Answer (score 0):

Amon's answer is correct, and this answer is really just a specific variation of the approach described in the first part of his answer:

When a request comes in, look in the cache based on the appropriate key(s).  If there's nothing there, create a new resource URI which will return the request result.  Start processing the result.  Put the URI in the cache and associate it with the request key.  Reply with a response which references that location.  You could use redirects for this if that's desirable.

When the client attempts to GET the response, if it has not yet completed you have a couple of choices.  You could either respond with a 'try again later' (or 'pending') response, or you could block on the server until the response is ready.  If your response should be created in a reasonably short period, you might be able to get away with the latter, but an immediate response is safer.

If you can come up with some sort of reasonable hashing scheme or mapping 'similar' requests to the same URI (which seems doable here) you could avoid race conditions where two or more requests come in so close together that you still end up processing the same request more than once (or have to come up with locking schemes to prevent it.)  That might be overkill here but it's fairly straightforward if you can work out a scheme.  That could also lead to building that logic right into the client, but I think doing it server side has some advantages, especially if you have to worry about different versions of the client.

The main challenge with this approach that you'll want to consider regardless of the approach is what happens if the processing fails to complete.  Then you could have all the clients waiting on something that never completes.  Consider how long it should take, what a reasonable timeout is, and how (or if) to retry if the background processing fails.